# Collection and cursor

Tags: oracle11g

I have suppose 1000 rows in a column. I wanted to update those 1000 rows by taking a chunk of 100 rows at a time and then keep updating 100 rows at a time till all 1000 rows are updated. How do I loop it in a procedure?

Comment: Unless this is homework you almost certainly do not want to process things in chunks.  Updating all 1000 at one time is faster and easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more column 'update_status' with default value 0.
Then execute below loop:-

> Loop
>      update table
>         set col = new_value
>             update_status = 1
>        where update_status = 0
>          and rownum <= 100;
>      Exit when SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0;
>   End Loop

Don't forget to drop the added column.

I think this might work.

Comment: Hey Jon thansk for your reply but can't it be done without adding a new column ??